# Trouble setting up a Gopher server on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I have been trying to host my own Gopher server under OS X (specifically, Snow Leopard), but am finding the process somewhat frustrating.

After trying (and failing) to install myriad supposedly cross-platform server packages, I settled for *Aftershock*, as it is the only one which seems to 'work' – and I use that word very loosely.

Ideally, I would like to host the server without the need for any specialised software, but in order to do so I need to know the name of the 'root document' a Gopher client looks for when connecting (e.g. Web browsers expect a file called `index` on a web site). Unfortunately, RFC 1436 (the document which specifies the standards of the Gopher protocol) only mentions what this mystery file must contain, but not its name.

I have tried using `!Gopher Links`, `.Link` and `.Links` as file names, but all result in an "Unable to access document" error when viewed using the command-line browser *lynx*.

I was directed here by the friendly folk over at *AskDifferent*, so if anyone is able to assist, I will be most obliged!

Comment: Gopher? Are you serious? Anyway, this is likely off-topic here as I can't imagine it to be in a professional environment. Please see the [FAQ].

Comment: Just to satisfy my intensely piqued curiosity... why on earth do you want to run a gopher server?

Answer (score 1):

The `LinkFileName` directive in the `aftershock.conf` file is where this file's name is described. The default value is `.Link`, which you state you've already tried. The software is written in Java, so I expect the formatting of the path value for the root directory `GopherRoot` will following any java-quirks relating to OSX path-naming.